# Can someone help me with solving my problem

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
void main() async {
  int myDelay = 5;
  print('Hello');
  var value = await _customDelay(myDelay);
  var customText = myDelay == 1 ? "second later" : "seconds later";
  print('Its $value $customText');
}

Future<int> _customDelay(int delay) async {
  try {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: delay));
    return delay;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return delay;
  }
}
```

It doesn't show in debug console or in my output and i have located my folder but still doesn't work

Comment: try to run on dartpad.dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  print("Hello");
  const int myDelay = 5;
  await _customDelay(myDelay);
  print('Its $myDelay ${myDelay == 1 ? "second" : "seconds"} later');
}

Future<void> _customDelay(int delay) async {
  return Future<void>.value(Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: delay)));
}
```